# margin-top leaves a blank space

Tags: html, css

I'm new at learning web development and I followed a Youtube tutorial on how to make a simple website I'm confused about why my `margin-top` leaves a blank space when the tutorial doesn't.

If I select the parent element the element like `.main__container button` instead of directly choosing the element `main__btn` it works, I'd like to know how to remove the blank white space if I use `.main__btn` and why it's not working in mine?

```css
.main__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #141414;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.main__btn {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to top, #f77062 0%, #fe5196 100%);
  padding: 14px 32px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  `your text` position: relative;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__container">
    <div class="main__content">
      <h1>NEXT GENERATION</h1>
      <h2>TECHNOLOGY</h2>
      <p>See what makes us different</p>
      <button><div class="main__btn"><a href="/">Get Started</a></div></button>
    </div>
    <div class="main__img--container">
      <img src="images/pict.svg" alt="pic" id="main__img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: an anchor inside a button is not valid HTML. You cannot nest interactive elements inside each other! If the Tutotiral taught you to do that, you should look for a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply fix your invalid markup and remove everything from the button with the exception of the text.
An interactive element such as the `<button>` can not contain other interactive elements such as `<a>` anchors. The only interactive element that can contain another interactive element is the `<label>` which is a specific case that is supposed to wrap a single interactive input element (e.g. `<input>`).

Always use a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to check if your markup fulfills the W3C and WHATWG specifications. It will solve most of your issues on its own.

```css
.main__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #141414;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.main__btn {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to top, #f77062 0%, #fe5196 100%);
  padding: 14px 32px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__container">
    <div class="main__content">
      <h1>NEXT GENERATION</h1>
      <h2>TECHNOLOGY</h2>
      <p>See what makes us different</p>
      <button class="main__btn">Get Started</button>
    </div>
    <div class="main__img--container">
      <img src="images/pict.svg" alt="pic" id="main__img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for answering! If it's okay I would like to ask how to redirect people to another page when they click the button if I can't use anchors inside the button? Would it work If i use .main__container button instead?

Comment: Well, you have to think about what you want to achieve. Either you want a button (input element to fire a script) or you want to redirect to other resource anchors. If you want the last, then use an anchor and style it as a button. Alternatively, you can use scripts with a button such as: `href.location = url`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about styling an anchor to become a button.